# EPiServer.LiveMonitor: Only root node is displayed in live monitor view

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have installed the `EPiServer.LiveMonitor` NuGet package, and set up the live monitor functionality.

However, when I click on the live monitor tab, I can only see the root node:
[image]

Does anyone know why I can't see my whole page structure?
I can neither see myself visiting the page in another tab, if that is useful information.

This is the root of the monitoring: `<monitoringTarget contentId="1" />`.
Content id `1` is the root node of my page.

EDIT: I found out that it works on our test server, but not in my local dev environment. I'm not sure why, maybe it is the IIS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer, but I found out that it works on our test server, but not in my local dev environment. I'm not sure why, maybe it is the IIS version.

Answer (score 0):

Id "1" is usually the root page, and not your start page. Try changing the ID to you start page instead.

Comment: I did, now I only see the start page. Does it have to be users on the different pages for the page tree to show?

Comment: I found out it works in our test environment, but not in my local dev environment. I'm not sure why, maybe it is the IIS version.